# SQL How to make the first column increment

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to make my first column in a table just automatically increment whenever a new row is added, however instead "*NULL*" is inserted there.

Here is my code for inserting a new row:

```
String update = "INSERT INTO help(name, area, date, message) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        connection = plugin.getHikari().getConnection();
        // Inserting into the table
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        // Replace the '?' with the actual information
        statement.setString(1, name);
        statement.setString(2, area);
        statement.setString(3, date);
        statement.setString(4, message);
        statement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is how I create my table:

```
 statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS help" +
                        "(" +
                        "id int," +
                        "name varchar(20)," +
                        "area varchar(25)," +
                        "date varchar(15)," +
                        "message varchar(255)" +
                        ")");
        statement.execute();
```

Here is a statement I run **everytime the application is loaded / starts up:**

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE help MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment");
```

Thanks,
 - Nicster

Comment: What db are you using? You've used both the mysql and Oracle tags but these dbs do it differently. Also, can you show the table's create sql so we know how you've set it up?

Comment: @SamM I've edited my main posts & tags. :)

Comment: make your `id` column `PRIMARY KEY`. Then modify it to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @1000111 what exactly does "PRIMARY KEY" mean? The column that is able to identify the row?

Comment: somewhat like : unique identifier of rows. A column value which differentiates the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything you need to in the create statement.  The problem is your id column is nullable and is not a primary key.

Just change your create statement to

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS help" +
                    "(" +
                    "id int not null auto_increment," +
                    "name varchar(20)," +
                    "area varchar(25)," +
                    "date varchar(15)," +
                    "message varchar(255)" +
                    "PRIMARY KEY (id)" +
                    ")");
    statement.execute();
```

You should not need the alter table statement. Hope that helps

Comment: Great answer Chris. @Nicster15, you don't need to run an alter table statement every time the application loads.

Comment: @Chris oh awesome. One question, what does "PRIMARY KEY" mean?

Comment: The primary key is the column (or columns) used to uniquely identify a record in a relational database.

Comment: For example if you had a database table with a list of people in it you might assign the primary key to be Social Security Number (SSN) as each SSN uniquely idetifies a person (provided they live in the US).

Answer (score 0):

Either you add a primary key to the table "PRIMARY KEY (id))" which would auto_increment itself, or you have have to use java logic to increment the value each time you insert the row

Comment: What exactly is a Primary Key? The way you identify the row?